# How to iterate a json object if it has combination of string,boolean and number type

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I had a `node.js` app where it takes JSON object and then it encrypts the JSON object key value. I had a function which takes value and then encrypts data. Now I need to iterate only the JSON key value to the function which I'm able to do using.

```
var JsonData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var callFunction = iterate(JsonData);

function iterate(JsonData) {
    for (var exKey in JsonData) {
        if (JsonData.hasOwnProperty(exKey)) {
            if (typeof JsonData[exKey] == "object") {
                iterate(JsonData[exKey]);
            } else {
                JsonData[exKey] = encrypt(JsonData[exKey]);
            }
        }
    }
}
var encrpted = JSON.stringify(JsonData);
```

But the problem is I'm able to iterate only the string type JSON object.i.e., (ex `{"name":"sam","gender":"male"}`). If we are having JSON object with `boolean` or number or both type along with string type,it is not able to iterate and I'm getting some error..(ex. `{"name":"sam","age":21,"isMarried":false}`).

So how can I iterate through that function if I have other than string type? I know that using replace function we can convert `boolean`, num type to string and then pass to function.But since I'm doing encryption and then decryption, here after decrypted we get everything in string type, which I don't want.They need to be in their original type.So I think this will not work. So can anyone suggest any ideas and help me. Hope my question is clear. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I don't understand why (or how) you expect to encrypt a boolean.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @TimoSta TypeError: Not a string or buffer
    at TypeError (native)

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Iam not particularly trying to encrypt boolean.Iam trying to encrypt json key value,which might be string,number or boolean type

Comment: If I understand you correctly, could you just encrypt everything as strings but also include type information in the string? Encrypt strings like `"String:sam"`, `"Number:21"`, `"Boolean:true"`, then, at decryption time, strip the type info from the string and convert to that type.

Comment: @apsillers I dont want everything to be encrypted.I need only key value to be encrypted.(ex;.{"name":"sam"} to {"name":"178fd995"}.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate and parse all properties of your JSON object, You could use Object.keys() this way :

```
obj = {
   booleanVar : true,
   numericVar : 125,
   stringVar : "a string"
};
var iterate = JsonData => Object.keys(JsonData).forEach(key => console.log(JsonData[key]));
iterate(obj); // true
              // 125
              // a string
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your first `if` condition .

Example :

```
function iterate(JsonData) {
    for (var exKey in JsonData) {
            if (typeof JsonData[exKey] == "object") {
                iterate(JsonData[exKey]);
            } else {
                JsonData[exKey] = encrypt(JsonData[exKey]);
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: No .This is not working.It is again giving me TypeError: Not a string or buffer
    at TypeError (native)